# Faster Userform Listbox filtering Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I'm developing a userform, and have a listbox in it. I'm loading the listbox, but only with select data, and based on different dropdowns in the userform as well. The sample sheet I have goes through 6000 lines, but I'm being told that it will eventually include 20,000+. It's already taking around ten seconds to filter. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Code is below:

```
For rowNum = isStartRow To isEndRow

    Dim h2T As String: h2T = iSH.Range(h2 & rowNum).Text
    Dim h3T As String: h3T = iSH.Range(h3 & rowNum).Text
    Dim h4T As String: h4T = iSH.Range(h4 & rowNum).Text
    Dim h5T As String: h5T = iSH.Range(h5 & rowNum).Text
    Dim descT As String: descT = UCase(iSH.Range(desc & rowNum).Text)

    If h2T Like "*" & Me.cmbo_H2.value & "*" And h3T Like "*" & Me.cmbo_H3.value & "*" And h4T Like "*" & Me.cmbo_H4.value & "*" And h5T Like "*" & Me.cmbo_H5.value & "*" And descT Like "*" & UCase(Me.txt_Search.value) & "*" And (iSH.Range("A" & rowNum) = 10 Or iSH.Range("A" & rowNum) = 20) Then

        If Not Exists(Me.cmbo_H2, h2T) Then Me.cmbo_H2.AddItem h2T
        If Not Exists(Me.cmbo_H3, h3T) Then Me.cmbo_H3.AddItem h3T
        If Not Exists(Me.cmbo_H4, h4T) Then Me.cmbo_H4.AddItem h4T
        If Not Exists(Me.cmbo_H5, h5T) Then Me.cmbo_H5.AddItem h5T

        Me.list_Items.AddItem iSH.Range(desc & rowNum).Text
        Me.list_Items.List(Me.list_Items.ListCount - 1, 1) = iSH.Range(codeCol & rowNum).Text
        Me.list_Items.List(Me.list_Items.ListCount - 1, 2) = iSH.Range(iNumber & rowNum).Text
        Me.list_Items.List(Me.list_Items.ListCount - 1, 3) = iSH.Range(moqCol & rowNum).Text

    End If

Next
```

Comment: don't read `.text`from Range, it's the slowest (instead read `.value2').
Still, if you put the full range in an array first, it's faster.
Also your IF's are horrible to look, my eyes bleed. Instead do one only condition, and if treu, do the next and so on. The rarest condition first. And finally, instead of `range()`, use `cells(y,x)`. Also use variables, instead of reading multiple times same range/cell ! Under a second result if you apply all of this.

Comment: This is funniest late comment I've ever seen. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

a more efficient way would be to read the range into an array and then do all processing within the array. Reading the sheet is costly in terms of processing time, read it once to an array and then process

This may help you http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

Comment: I was considering that. I'll give it a shot

Comment: No go... still same speed